# Problem In Send Parameters of View to Lib in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem for define def in Django.
this is My View.py

```
import logging
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Saham_Status, Saham_Pay
from azbankgateways import bankfactories, models as bank_models, default_settings as settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from .forms import Saham_Pays
from time import gmtime, strftime

class SahamSta_ListView(ListView):
   template_name = 'forms/display_forms.html'
   context_object_name = 'saham_st'
   model = Saham_Status

   def get_queryset(self):
      return self.model.object.all().filter(user_name=self.request.user)

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(SahamSta_ListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['form'] = Saham_Pays

      return context

  class Sta_Pay_ListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'forms/statuse_pay.html'
    context_object_name = 'sta_pay'
    model = Saham_Pay

   def get_queryset(self):
      return self.model.objects.all().filter(user_name=self.request.user)

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(Sta_Pay_ListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['form'] = Saham_Pays
      return context
   #this part
   def get_payid():
   pay_id = Saham_Status.object.all().filter(saham_pay_id=)
   return pay_id
```

Now this is Lib in Django Lib for send parameters(p.py):

```
def get_pay_data(self):
    data = {
        'terminalId': int(self._terminal_code),
        'userName': self._username,
        'userPassword': self._password,
        'orderId': int(self.get_tracking_code()),
        'amount': int(self.get_gateway_amount()),
        'localDate': self._get_current_date(),
        'localTime': self._get_current_time(),
        'additionalData': description,
        'callBackUrl': self._get_gateway_callback_url(),
        'payerId': get_payid()
    }
    return data
```

and this models.py:

```
class Saham_Status(models.Model):
  user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  saham_pay_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, default=None)
```

I want to send a parameter(saham_pay_id = field in db) of database that user login to p.py('payerId': get_payid()) and this function get_payid() defined in views.py.

Help Me.